# Triangle relationships

Tags: geometry, triangles

I was wondering if someone can help me actually. You see I came upon this book called Mathematics for Physics by Michael and Malcolm Woolfson. 
I a presently stuck on the very first exercise and I can 't seem to find an answer to the question. Unfortunately there isn't a segment showing the workings so I am left to wonder how the hell do I solve this? Nevertheless it has lead me through a multitude of areas that explore the subject matter and in spite of not answering the question yet, I have learned a lot.

But I digress...

The Question goes "Find the side and angles of a triangle with a = 5, b = 6, B = 50 degrees

Just to clarify a few things; this here is a scalene triangle that we are trying to resolve. I will describe is as Triangle ABC (Representing the three angles of the triangles) with a pependicular CP from apex C to side AB (otherwise known as the adjacent). 
The sides are of lengths a, b and c and the perpendicular is of length h.

I have been given the formula a/sin A = b/sinB = c/sin C

How would you go about solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Given a, b and B, we can obtain A using

> a/sin A = b/sinB

Given A and B, we can obtain C (how?).

Given C, we can obtain c using either

> b/sinB = c/sin C

or

> a/sin A = c/sin C

Answer (score 0):

You have $a, b$ and $B$.  You know that 
$$
\frac{a}{\sin A} = \frac{b}{\sin B}$$
and in that equation three of the quantities are known, so you can solve for 
$\sin A = \frac56 \sin 50 $.

Now you can use a calculator or whatever to find $A$ by using the inverse sine function.  Having $A$ and $B$ you then use your knowledge that the sum of the angles in a triangle is 180 to find $C$.  Then use the law of sines one last time$$
\frac{c}{\sin C} = \frac{b}{\sin B}$$ to find $c$.